# ListView - Button changes text on the same row but when scroll down it changes text on another row

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

The problem is when I click on itemTwo(button) it changes the itemNum text for that row and another row, and vise versa.
For example; on row 1: if i click on the button it changes the text for that row but also the text for row 6 when i scroll down.

So row 1 and 6 changes each other same with row 2 and 7, and row 3 and 8.

When I scroll back up the text on row one goes default and row 2 changes to row one's previous text and went i go scroll down and go back up some of the rows text change without clicking on the button

Side Note: My list view has 7 rows but it only show 4 rows. ListView has a height of 196dp and each cell/row has a height of 49dp.

```
public class Holder : Java.Lang.Object
                {
                public TextView itemName
                    public TextView itemNum
                    public Button itemOne;
                    public Button itemTwo;
                    public int pos;

                public void Initialize(View view)
                {
                itemName = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.itemNameTextView);
                    itemNum = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.itemNumTextView);
                    itemOne = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.itemOneButton);
                    itemTwo = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.itemTwoButton);
                    itemTwo.Click += itemClick;
                }

                public void Bind(Activity context, string gn, int one, int two,  int num, int position)
                {
                    itemtName.Text = gn;
                    itemOne.Tag = one;
                    itemTwo.Tag = two;
                itemNum.Tag = num;
                    pos = position;
                }

                public void itemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

                    int s = (int)clickedButton.Tag;

                    Console.WriteLine (s.ToString ());
                    switch ((int)clickedButton.Tag)
                    {
                    case 122:
                        itemNum.Text = "1";
                        break;
                    case 222:
                        itemNum.Text = "2";
                        break;
                    case 322:
                        itemNum.Text = "3";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


private class ItemListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Item>
        {
            private Activity activity;
            public List<Item> data;

            public ItemListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Item> data)
            {
                this.activity = activity;
                this.data = data;
            }
            public override Item this[int position]
            {
                get { return this.data [position]; }
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get { return this.data.Count(); }
                //get {return 5;}
            }

            public override long GetItemId(int position)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                Holder holder;

                if (convertView == null) 
                {
                    convertView = this.activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.GarmentItem, null);
                    holder = new Holder ();
                    holder.Initialize (convertView);
                    convertView.Tag = holder;   
                }

            Item item = this.data [position];
            holder = (Holder)convertView.Tag;
                holder.Bind (this.activity, item.itemName, item.itemOneTag, item.itemTwoTag, itemNumTag, position);

                return convertView;    
            }
```

Comment: this doesn't happened when i set the list view height to wrap_content

Answer (score 1):

Android reuses Views in its collections. So what's happening right now is you click on a cell and the text of itemNum gets set. Then when you scroll, the view of the cell you clicked on gets reused for a new item in the collection. Since you aren't setting a default value for itemNum, the value that was set previously carries over.

To fix this, you should set the default values of all items in the View. In this case, if you set itemNum.text to an empty string in your Bind method, it will solve your current issue.

Comment: I don't want to use the default values. On a row; when the button is click, it would increment/count number of click and set that number to the textfield. So when I go scroll up or down, I want that number to show for the row.

Comment: Right, but you can't just hold the value from the click in the holder. Holders are reused as the cell they were first used by gets scrolled off the screen.

What you need to do is create a way, via the ClickHandler, to pass the new ItemNum up to the Item level. Then when your cell re-binds, and calls 
GetView, it passes the view with the new ItemNum info into the holder. I'll post an example later if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click the button you will need to set a tag once again, when you have an item in a row on the list view, you will need to make sure to reset the tag after avery change